# Qt conditional file includes in .pro

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

I have a problem with including a file through ".pro" file.
If the ARCH equals "64bit" ,this is an environment variable of my system, I will include a 'function1.h' to my project.
else, include 'function2.h'

But only a message works properly and both files are included together.
I mean, I only can see a Project Message saying "Hello 64-bit" , but I can see two files in my project file list. function1.h and function2.h.

what's the problem and how can I make this out

here is my code

```
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

OS_IS = $$(ARCH)

equals(OS_IS,64bit){
    message("Hello 64-bit")
    HEADERS += function1.h
}else{
    message("Hello 32-bit")
    HEADERS += function2.h
}

...
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem must be in other place. This is working to me as expected:

```
OS_IS = $$(ARCH)

message("Headers before:" $$HEADERS)

equals(OS_IS,"64bit"){
    message("Hello 64-bit")
    HEADERS += function1.h
}else{
    message("Hello 32-bit")
    HEADERS += function2.h
}

message("Headers after:" $$HEADERS)
```